# Vertically centering a Flash website in a small browser resolution

Tags: css, flash, browser, height

We have recently made a new Flash website for our company (http://www.hrhent.com). The Flash module itself is 800 pixels tall. We have CSS that centers a div horizontally and vertically that's wrapped around the Flash module (you can see the source of http://www.hrhent.com) and when someone is on a browser on a netbook or a smaller laptop (sub 15-inch, generally), they don't have enough vertical resolution (after the real estate used by the Windows start bar and browser toolbars) to see the entire site.

Whether you view the html page I've made (again, at http://www.hrhent.com) or you view the Flash module itself (http://www.hrhent.com/main_v10.swf) the top of the Flash module clips off the top of the browser. (To see the problem if you don't have a small laptop, just don't maximize your browser window and shrink it's vertical height.)

I understand *why* my CSS is behaving the way it is, due to the nature of the negative top margin, but is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: ANY way? Or does it have to be a CSS solution?

Answer (score 0):

One approach that may work is to use stage.stageHeight to find the browser's height and shift everything down based on that.